# Call requires API level 21 (current min is 10)" ao usar getDrawable()

Tags: android

Quando tento comparar o *Drawable* de um *ImageButton* com um determinado *Drawable* acontece esse erro *"Call requires API level 21 (current min is 10)"*.

Estou utilizando o `getDrawable().getConstantState()` para pegar o *Drawable* do *ImageButton* e dando um `.equals(getDrawable(R.drawable.img))` no que quero comparar.

Tentei usar `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img).getConstantState()` porém dava como *getDrawable(int id) is deprecated*

Meu gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.gustavo.meuapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Logcat ao compilar da esses erros:

```
05-23 11:57:07.084  12236-12236/com.app.gustavo.meuapp E/﹕ Device driver API match
Device driver API version: 23
User space API version: 23
```

e na execução ao chegar na linha do

```
imgButton.getDrawable().equals(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img))
```

dá esses:

```
05-23 11:57:35.219  12236-12236/com.app.gustavo.meuapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.app.gustavo.meuapp.VsDroid.jogadaDroid(VsDroid.java:54)
            at com.app.gustavo.meuapp.VsDroid.clickQuadrado(VsDroid.java:40)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sua aplicação está com a configuração para Android desde 2.3.3. Para isso há duas alternativas:

1) Modificar no gradle a API mínima para 21, atributo **minSdkVersion**

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

2) Segundo a documentação [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable%28%29] o getDrawable() foi inserido na API 1, você está usando assim? imageButton.getDrawable?

2.1) Para pegar um drawable do resource basta fazer assim:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.image );
```

EDIT:

Você está usando o support v7 errado, o 22 é para API 21. No dependence usa assim:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
```

Pelo o que eu entendi você quer verificar se um botão está com a imagem certa, é isso? Essa não é a melhor maneira para fazer isso, porque ficar carregando drawables na memória só para comprar não é performático. Sugiro que você guarde o id do resource e verifique por ela. Exemplo:

```
private imagemAtual = R.drawable.imagem1;

private void trocarImagem(int imageResource){
    imagemAtual = imageResource;
    imageButton.setImageResource(imageResource);
}
```

Quando quiser saber qual imagem está :

```
if(imagemAtual == R.drawable.imagemParaComparar)
```

Comment: Discussão movida para o [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24107/discussion-on-answer-by-jader-alcantara-call-requires-api-level-21-current-min).